# How to use a member function from a parent class with the same name (via this->)?

Tags: c++, oop, object, this

Heres the gist of my program:

I have a base class called **Person**. It has a child called **President**. I am trying to create a "printInfo" function in the **President** class that prints all of its attributes from **both classes**.

The simplest change was to simply differentiate the functions by changing the names, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this without changing them.

*(The code below just includes the relevant parts, I left out a bunch of other member functions to make it easier to read)*

```
class Person : public Address {
public:
    void printInfo(); // this prints the name and birthday
private:
    string fname, lname, sex;
    int month, day, year;
};

class President : public Person {
private:
    int term;
public:
    void printInfo(); // this prints term
};

void President::printInfo() {
    cout << term << "  :  ";
    this->printInfo(); //need this to use the person version of itself
};
```

What I want:

```
1 : George Washington ....
```

Actual Result:

```
1 : 1 : 1 : ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the member function of base class by adding `Person::` prefix. e.g.

```
void President::printInfo() {
    cout << term << "  :  ";
    Person::printInfo();
};
```

BTW: It's better to make `printInfo` and the destructor of `Person` `virtual`.